# WSO2 API Manager where to store the private key

Tags: ssl, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

i was trying to install CA certified certificates in WSO2 API Manager.
But i have not found any place which tells about where to store the private key?
Is private key not needed to make SSL work?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the key store  in

```
[AM]\repository\resources\security\wso2carbon.jks
```

and the client truststore in

```
[AM]\repository\resources\security\client-truststore.jks
```

Using  keytool you can install any certificate. The default password = wso2carbon

For SSL you need to store the public certificate not the private key

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a new JKS keystore with your private key and certificate chain (so there is no confusion with the existing wso2carbon.jks). you can configure the SSL settings in repository/config/tomcat/catalina-server.xml.

One of the common practices is having a proxy server in front of the APIM doing the SSL termination, load balancing  and  controlling access to the publisher, store and gateway.